# Reading questions form a txt file and comparing answers with another txt file in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, sh

What I'm trying to do is display the questions stored in a text file passed by parameter `$1` then read and store in an array and compare with the right questions stored in another text file passed by the parameter `$2` and then count the number right and wrong but for some reason, it validates all the questions as right in a majority of the trays.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
declare -a answers
i=0
while read -r line;
do
        answers+=("$line")
        while read -r question;
        do
                echo "$question"
                read -r "[YES/NO]" line
        done < "$1"
done

while read -r lines;
do
        if ((lines == ${answers[$i]}));
        then
                correct=$((correct + 1))
        else
                incorrect=$((incorrect + 1))
        fi
i=$((i + 1))
done < "$2"
echo correct $correct
echo incorrect $incorrect
```

Comment: Run your script through shellcheck: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: In the first part of your script, I think you want to bring the `read` operation to the top, instead of the `for`; so `while read -r line ...`, and do `answers+=($line)`.

Comment: And then the input as follows: `while read ...do ... done < "$1"`, like you did in the second part.

Comment: I have edit the code the way you said and edit the post in here as well but now is not working at all and is printing the questions word by word instead of line by line

Comment: Without seeing your data, it's hard to imagine what this should be doing. `((lines == ${answers[$i]}))` is an arithmetic expression, but is `lines` really expected to be a number here?

Comment: lines is expected to be a string in fact the file passed on the second parameter contain a set of lines with yes or no answers although when I use ' -eq ' it still fails